# Calculate mean of set values based on array position and counter

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I have two vectors in MATLAB as follows:

```
  Crossing Time = [11 14 16 18 29 18 53 22 18 11 19 10 15 15 13 18];

          Count = [0  0  2  3  0  0  4  3  6  2  5  0  3  5  2  7];
```

I want to calculate mean of crossing time based on the count. 
For example: If count is zero, corresponding crossing time is just the value from the crossing time vector 
i.e. for first zero in count vector, crossing time is 11 and for second zero the crossing time is 14. This is straightforward. 
However, if the count is non-zero, such as 2 (third column in count vector), I want the mean of 2nd and 3rd columns of crossing time vector beside 2 
(i.e. mean of 14 and 16 beside 2). 
If the count is 4 (7th column in count vector) then I want the mean of 4th to 7th columns of the crossing time vector.

In doing that I would have the following mean vector:

```
          Mean = [11 14 15 16 29 18 29.5 31 26.33 14.5 24.6 10 14.67 14 14 14.43]
```

How can I do this in a loop so that I can repeat this for my huge vectors with 90,000 records. It should be straightforward for any programmer but unfortunately I have very limited programming knowledge.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: and what happens if the count is **1**?

Comment: there shouldn't be any single count. It is either 0 or 2+. Thanks!

Comment: I added a new solution, check if it works for you as fell. Should be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no `Count = 1` but `Count = 0` behaves like `Count = 1`,

```
Count(~Count) = 1;
cs = [0 cumsum(CrossingTime)];    
meanVal = arrayfun(@(x,y) (cs(x+1) - cs(1 + x-y))/y, 1:numel(Count), Count)
```

---

The loop could be as follows:

```
Count(~Count) = 1
meanVal = zeros(1,numel(CrossingTime));
for ii = 1:numel(CrossingTime)
    meanVal(ii) = mean( CrossingTime(ii:-1:ii-Count(ii)+1));
end
```

---

Alternatively use `arrayfun`, which is basically the same:

```
Count(~Count) = 1
meanVal = arrayfun(@(x) mean( CrossingTime(x:-1:x-Count(x)+1)), 1:numel(Count))
```

Comment: Nice. There is no need to change `Count` if you change you `arrayfun` call to this: `meanVal = arrayfun(@(x) mean( CrossingTime(min(x,x-Count(x)+1):x)), 1:numel(Count))`.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I don't see any advantage doing that.

Comment: This is great!!!! The script is working perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help @thewaywewalk

Comment: @thewaywewalk It's just to avoid changing the input array. We never know if it will be used by any other part of the code. :)

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro yes sure, that makes sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

@thewaywewalk gave a nice answer. Just for the record, here is a modified version which precomputes the sums to run faster:

```
cumulative = [0 cumsum(CrossingTime)];
meanVal = arrayfun(@(x) (cumulative(x + 1) - cumulative(x - max(Count(x), 1) + 1)) / max(Count(x), 1), 1:numel(Count));
clear cumulative;
```

Running times with a randomized 90.000 array (as mentioned on the question):

- thewaywewalk' solution (using loops): **10.163953 seconds**
- thewaywewalk' solution (using arrayfun): **11.339777 seconds**
- my solution (precomputing + arrayfun): **0.371947 seconds**

**NOTE:** The array was created using this:

```
N = 90000;
CrossingTime = randi(10000, 1, N);
Count = min(0:N-1, randi(N, 1, N) - 1);
```

Comment: Your generated `count` variable goes up multiple ten thousands, then I understand the differences in speed. But I think these count numbers are for out from the OP's scope ;)

Comment: I added another solution, which again could be faster than yours.

Comment: Actually the OP said that: "(...) my huge vectors with 90,000 records". I tested your new solution and the running times are [virtually the same](http://pastebin.com/Z6aUtpbe), but that's the spirit. :)

Comment: that's not what I mean. The OP has a vector with the **length** of 90000, but your generated `count` vector has **values** of multiple then thousands.